# intellij - open files disappear from view while I'm using them

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Not sure if this is a bug or if there's a setting I need to adjust, so I'm posting this question in case it's the latter. I just updated my IntelliJ Community Edition to 2022.2.5.

I have my Java project listed in the Project view (it happens with every project I've worked on so far). I'm doing Java work, so I go to the src folder and go through the folders and find a class to work on, say PolicyService.java. I have that open and am looking through it, and may or may not be making changes to it. I then go to my PaymentsService.java and open it, so now I have two classes open and in view (not sure of the name of the window on the screen where you have the file open and are editing them). Then maybe I open a few more (although it happens when I have just one file open also).

Then suddenly, all the files disappear from the view, and the Project view suddenly collapses all the open folders so it looks like I didn't open any folders. Just project-name folder, along with the folders on the same level for External Libraries and Scratches and Consoles.

What's even weirder is what happens to the breadcrumbs in the bar above the Project view and the open file view. It was normal when I had the file open - project-name > src > main > java > com > am > api > appdesk > service > PolicyService > whatever method I was on. But when the file disappears it changes to Sample > sample > sample > sample > sample > sample > sample > sample > sample > sample > (can't remember what it said in place of the method). It stays like that for a few minutes, and then the breadcrumbs disappear.

The other interesting thing is that when I go to open one of the files again, instead of showing the top of the file, the file opens at precisely the point I had it open before it disappears.

Does anybody know what's going on with this? I did a quick Google search on files disappearing from view and didn't see anything about any bugs. A few of the search results that came up had to do with files actually disappearing from the folders themselves, but that's not happening here. The files are still there in the folders, they just disappear from the editor view.

Is this a know bug? Is this potentially a new bug? Is there some new setting I need to change? Is it anything else?

Any help or input is appreciated.

Comment: Consider Invalidate Caches / Restart first, update to the newer version of IntelliJ second, check some custom plugins you're using third, and finally submit a ticket to IntelliJ Comunity YouTrack here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your files away from the cloud sync managed folder and open the project from the new location. Cloud sync software such as OneDrive and Dropbox can interfere with the file system operations and remove local files to save space (keeping only shortcuts to them and download the files on the fly when you try to access them). IDE is not designed to work with files that are not available offline.

Comment: The files are not in a cloud sync managed folder. Sorry if I said something that gave that impression. They are on a network drive though, although it is a wired network. Would that cause the same issue? I can move the repository to my local hard drive. I only put it on a network drive because on my previous laptop I had run out of drive space, so I'm trying to prevent that with my new laptop.

Comment: Yes, network drive connection can also cause such problems. Always use local drive for the projects.