# Intellij - Project Files disappear from view while using them - Mac OS

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

While working with IntelliJ(v2023.3.4 - Community Ed), after stopping my Kotlin code from running, the project files disappear. They don't come back until I reopen the IDE or update some settings within the IDE.

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76672547/intellij-open-files-disappear-from-view-while-im-using-them) which says, in summary, remove the files from a cloud synced folder. I'm using a Mac OS and I don't recall creating the code in a cloud synced folder.
PS: It's in the Documents folder.

How can I check if it's in a cloud synced folder and remove it from a cloud synced folder?

Or basically, how can I get it to stop disappearing?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show a video of the issue reproduction?
Can you please try to reproduce the issue in a new project in the exact location? In addition, try to reproduce the issue in another project in another folder.
I think it is worth creating a ticket to YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue

Comment: I tried this. I created a project in another folder (Desktop), and when I ran the project, the project files didn't disappear. But when I ran it from any location in the Documents folder, they disappeared. Link to the video: [here](https://youtu.be/hE5iN6wFs0g)

I checked the folder info of both locations, there were no differences.

Comment: I have the exact same problem! Have you found a solution? I am confronted with this issue only using PyCharm 2023.3.5 (Professional Edition), with PyCharm 2022.3.1 (Community Edition) everything works well. I have to say the Professional Edition is quite demanding for my CPU. Seems like it's poorly optimized compared to the 2022 CE. 
I am on macOS Ventura 13.1.